# Why am i getting a score of zero using cross val score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, confusion-matrix, k-fold

> When i run this proccessing with 10 fold cross-validation,prediction
>   results is precisely opposite of label datas and i get zero accuracy.I
>   can not solve why is that?

```
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5,random_state=+7,shuffle=False)
predictions = model_selection.cross_val_predict(SVC(),features_list,labels_list,cv=kfold)
accuracy=metrics.accuracy_score(labels_list,predictions)
print(confusion_matrix(labels_list,predictions))
print(classification_report(labels_list,predictions))
print("Accuracy Score:",accuracy)
```

Comment: always add at least the programming language tag, so more people will see the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `cross_val_predict` to evaluate a model in scikit-learn (warning section there: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation)

Instead, use `cross_val_score` which will return 10 accuracies for the 10 models tested on the 10 different datasets built from cross-validation. Look at the mean score and std. dev. for the evaluation.

Comment: when i change it like this:cv= model_selection.cross_val_score(SVC(),features_list,labels_list,cv=kfold)
print(cv)    i get [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ] again ,when i print predict,this is precisely opposite matrix of label matrix.

Comment: Your model is maybe bad. However, you should use `shuffle=True` when creating CV. In case that your labels are sorted, you might get fold without all classes. Otherwise use the `StratifiedKfold` instead which will take of that matter.

Comment: i can send you the data to your mail,if you have time,because i also tried what you said and it did not work.